# How is Python able to distinct type names of namedtuples?

Tags: python, namedtuple

My model class has to provide lots of queries and I would like to return query results as namedtuple. My solution is working, but I don't know why :) - so I would like to get some clarification whether this is a good or valid design - or not.

Simplified sample code:

```
class SomeModel():
    def query01(self):
        Row = namedtuple("Row", "a")
        row = Row("a1")
        return row

    def query02(self):
        Row = namedtuple("Row", "a b c")
        row = Row(1,2,3)
        return row

sample = SomeModel()
item01 = sample.query01()
item02 = sample.query02()
print(item01)
print(item02)
```

The output is completely as expected:

```
Row(a='a1')
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Now for the unexpected ...

```
print(type(item01))
print(type(item02))
```

will provide:

```
<class '__main__.Row'>
<class '__main__.Row'>
```

If I would replace the namedtuples within the function with local classes the types would look as expected:

```
<__main__.query01.<locals>.Row at 0x11073eb30>
<__main__.query02.<locals>.Row at 0x11073fcd0>
```

Finally my question:

I would prefer the `namedtuple` approach over classes and it works like expected, but it feels a little bit strange that the type names are complete identical. How is Python able to distinct the two items, when their type names are the same? The naming convention for local classes make much more sense for me. Is it safe, to use namedtuple this way?

You can argue that I could use different namedtuple names inside my functions, but with lots of queries you can not guaranty that the names are always unique.

Comment: they are not identical

Comment: One of the reasons that people give for using namedtuple is that it has lower memory use than a normal object. However, if you create a new namedtuple class for each namedtuple object, that benefit no longer exists, because the namedtuple class takes memory too.

Comment: For the same reason there can be multiple people named "Markus". It's just a name, not an identity.

Comment: "How is Python able to distinct the two items, when their type names are the same?" - their *types* aren't the same, because they were *created by* separate calls to `namedtuple`. In fact, *every time either method is called* creates a distinct type that happens to have the same name (`__name__` attribute). I duplicate-linked the general canonical because this falls out naturally from how `namedtuple` is implemented.

Comment: Adding to @NickODell: If you are going to use `namedtuple`, *always* define them *once*, at global scope. Putting them in a function will make the code significantly slower, and make the overhead of the returned object well over a KB of memory (before counting the size of any data it stores), thanks to the class-per-instance design.

Comment: Actually, there should be a duplicate somewhere generally explaining the `__name__` attribute of types and how it's used by `__repr__` etc. That might be a better explanation.

Comment: In python, no object has a name, just an address in memory - well, in cpython that is. Names exist in namespaces and objects ar bound to them. If I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`,  I could do `Bar, Foo = Foo, Bar` and rename them both. `namedtuple` creates classes and is free to name its classes anything it wants. The name is informational only, it value has no real consequence in python.

Answer (score 1):

They are **not identical**:

If you add:

```
print(type(item01) is type(item02))
```

It will print `False`.

Types are *just objects* like any other. Their name's can be identical. It doesn't make the type identical. This expectation of yours is simply false. Note an even simpler case:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> foo2 = Foo()
>>> type(foo1), type(foo2)
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>)
>>> type(foo1) is type(foo2)
False
>>> print(isinstance(foo1, Foo), isinstance(foo2, Foo))
False True
```

The only reason this would be unsafe is if *some code* depended on unique types having unique names. But since that isn't a guarantee, that code would be fundamentally unsound, though.

But note, you should take care **not to unnecessarily recreate a named tuple class for each instance of the tuple**. That is unnecessarily wasteful.

```
Row = namedtuple("Row", "a b c")
```

Should be at the *module level*.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you (and all the others above) for providing this valuable insights.